# How to know what triggers reactivity

Tags: meteor

I have a (Iron) Router.onBeforeAction that is triggered more than once.
I know for sure that it is a reactivity source that has changed somehow.

How can I know what triggers reactivity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't always know, because `Tracker.dependency` can be abstracted away from your view, especially when using external modules / packages.

See: https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#tracker_dependency

You will have to look into the code of the packages on which you assume to be reactive (like `ReactiveVar`) and check at which point it calls `dependency.changed`.

Comment: OK, I knew that would be the case. Thanks